# Error: column p.proisagg does not exist in PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql, navicat

When I tried to copy paste the tables from my connection database and paste the tables into my local database in postgres I'm getting this error. I've been using navicat version 12 and postgres version 11. Is there any conflict in terms of versioning between the two extension?

*Some resources says: p.proisagg should change into p.prokind: the question is how can I change this? I've been using windows.It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance.*

[image]

Comment: "* p.proisagg should change into p.prokind: the question is how can I change this?*" - you can't. The Navicat code needs to be changed. Apparently your Navicat version is not compatible with Postgres 11 (or newer). You need to check the Navicat website for updates of the tool.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Navicat, version 12 does have support for PostgreSQL version 11. Check their customer center: https://customer.navicat.com

Answer (score 0):

The software version(navicat version 12) is inconsistent with the PGSQL version(postgres version 11). As a result, some configurations are not associated. You can upgrade the software version to resolve the problem,like navicat 15 or final (now is 16).

Comment: There is a relationship between them, software version adaptation issues.